# Find all elements intersecting the specific element - RaphaelJs

Tags: javascript, raphael

I have got multiple elements in my canvas. I want to find all elements that are intersecting/overlapping currently chosen element.

Is there a way to find this out in raphael Js???

**EDIT**
To clarify further, lets suppose I get an element by getByID(), is there a way for me to get **ALL** elements(that are already present in canvas) that intersect with it.

Comment: did you even try looking for it? open raphael source code and search for "intersect".

Comment: of course I did. For a day. You say as with such disdain as if you know the answer? Pls do not assume. Also did you even care to read the whole topic? if you havent read so far - read my answer below. An additional library gives the solution - but its requires mootools. Next time you want to give suggestion - be sure what you are suggesting.

Comment: you didn't even need to look at the source, both methods are available in documentation: http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html – search for "intersect" and then "bbox".

Comment: if it was so simple then I wouldnt have asked the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thought a little bit more and I think the best solution should be converting the elements into paths and then comparing if they are intersecting.  (I have used jQuery in my example, but ou can easily do it without jQuery).

```
intersectArray=new Array();  
paper.forEach(function (e) {
    isIntersection=Raphael.pathIntersection(currentElement.attr("path"), e.attr("path"));  //Need to check with currentElement
    if(!jQuery.isEmptyObject(isIntersection)) intersectArray[]=e.node.id; //assuming e has got ID. You can put any identifier for e.
}
```

I dont think that for `rect` and `circle` you can get a path. But  it is pretty easy to write a function for converting `rect` into path (since you know x,y all you need to do is add combination of width and Height). For `circle` use [this link](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/raphaeljs/6gH8TiOWlAw).

I was hoping to get a function embedded in Raphael that could do this, but as Joker said "*Can't rely on anyone these days, you have to do everything yourself, don't we*!". Just Kidding. RaphaelJs is damn neat.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use [`Raphael.isBBoxIntersect`](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Raphael.isBBoxIntersect) which accepts bounding boxes as arguments (returned from [`Element.getBBox`](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.getBBox).

```
// Creates canvas 320 × 200 at 10, 50
var paper = Raphael(10, 50, 320, 200);
// Creates circle at x = 50, y = 40, with radius 10
var circle = paper.circle(50, 40, 10);
// Sets the fill attribute of the circle to red (#f00)
circle.attr("fill", "#f00");
// Sets the stroke attribute of the circle to white
circle.attr("stroke", "#fff");

var circle2 = paper.circle(60, 40, 10);
// Sets the fill attribute of the circle to red (#f00)
circle2.attr("fill", "blue");
// Sets the stroke attribute of the circle to white
circle2.attr("stroke", "#fff");

alert(
  Raphael.isBBoxIntersect(
    circle.getBBox(),
    circle2.getBBox()
  )
);
```

Example of this code working: http://jsbin.com/uwiyeg/1/edit

**UPD**. There is [`getIntersectionList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff972182%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) SVG method which “returns the list of graphics elements whose rendered content intersects the supplied rectangle”. But this doesn't seem support across all browsers.

Comment: This doesnt solve my problem - two issues: Firstly I need identifiers of all elements and then run this function. But I dont have them. Even if I retrieve them, I will run Raphael.isBBoxIntersect for n-1 times. This looks a tad inefficient. Secondly, and more importantly, here BBox comparison is being done. This will not work for irregular polygons as BBox shape is not same as underlying elements shape.

Comment: where in your question did you mention "irregular polygons"?

Comment: where did i mention 'rectangle' in my question?? Your solution will not work for any other shape but for a rectangle. In fact your  jsbin example itself will not work because you gave an example of circle. BBox will only work for rectangles.

Comment: seriously, dude – https://www.google.com/search?q=intersection+of+polygons+raphael – look at first result

Comment: No it doesnt. That will let me know the intersection if I know the exact shapes of all polygons. What you have been telling me is extrapolating a function that can tell if two polygons intesect and use it multiple times to find out if all polygons intersect. That is as simple as it gets. What I am looking for is: I have identifier of ONLY 1 element. I have no info about other elements in canvas. Can i get the intersecting elements?

Comment: anyways tx for trying to help me!

Comment: I don't understand how do you want to find out about intersecting elements without having references to all elements on the screen. You have to be able to query other elements to know their coordinates. There is no magic way of saying "are there elements at this point of screen" and even if there was, you'd have to calculate it for all pixels of your currently selected shape.

Comment: yes there is a way for that: Paper.getElementsByPoint(x, y). And thats exactly the reason I asked this question: Is there a easier way??? If you take a look at my answer, that claims an easier way. I am still looking at it before I can state its correct.

Comment: Offtopic: That was the reason I chose SVG over Canvas. Because SVG creates dom elements and remembers them, whereas canvas paints and forgets. So there should be an elegant way to get my solution.

Comment: If you look at the source, you still reference all elements on the paper and verify if some point is within elements or not. https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/blob/master/raphael.js#L2594

Comment: You could actually store your shape positions / paths in objects properties and do the same in canvas.